# angular 2/4 how to get parent module name (id) in child module?

Tags: angular

I write RBAC permission module and the main idea is that every module may have own roles. 
If it is not root module I want that it extends roles from parent module. And to do this I need to get parent module name inside forChild. How can I do this?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class NgxPermissionModule {
  static forChild(roles): ModuleWithProviders {
    //i need to get parentModule here
  }
}
```